# How do I chroot php-fpm (7.3) for use with Apache 2.4.10?

Tags: php, apache, fpm

I would like to chroot my php-fpm service to /var/www/html for security reasons. I have a vhost in Apache 2.4.10 that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html /index.php /index.html

        <FilesMatch \.php$>
                SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
        </FilesMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is when I set `chroot = /var/www/html` in the pool .conf in php-fpm, the file paths sent from Apache are incorrect (due to the `DocumentRoot` it will set SCRIPT_FILENAME to `/var/www/html/index.php`, when php-fpm would now expect `/index.php`). I can kind of work around this by doing `AliasMatch \.php$ /` to get my php files out of the `DocumentRoot` folder, but this prevents the `DirectoryIndex` from working, because now Apache looks for `/index.php` as the index file, which doesn't exist. I'm assuming this is probably also pretty bad form...

Is there a way to handle this? I know nginx can get around this by rewriting SCRIPT_FILENAME, but this isn't an option for me. I also know I can set the `doc_root` php.ini option, but I've heard this can be a problem because it affects the `$_SERVER` variables related to the script path in php.

On a related note, how insecure is it to run php-fpm not in a chroot? (I have set `open_basedir` to /var/www/html)

Comment: [This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/733230/apache-file-not-found-after-setting-up-php-fpm-chroot/735200#735200) suggested to use `ProxyPassMatch` instead of `FileMatch` for similar case. Please try that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had actually been running with `ProxyPassMatch` initially and couldn't get it to work, but it looks like maybe I was having a separate setup issue at the time, as it appears to work for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use to run PHP in a chroot, however, it is a real pain for not a huge security benefit.  The biggest issue I ran into was trying to get all of the dependent shared objects into the chroot and keep them up to date after each system update. I eventually gave up and ended up running a reverse proxy with different user:group for each vhost instead of trying to chroot.  If you have 2 pools running as www:site1 and www:site2 you can chown root:site1 /var/www/site1 and then chmod 750 /var/www/site1.  This will prevent a hacked vhost (site2) from bleeding over into other vhosts (site1). Most of the other files on the server should be secure, but you still want to have outbound iptable rules and should make sure your session storage is using mode 600 if you are using the file storage engine.  You may also want to explore the disable_functions ini setting for additional security.

Comment: This is something like what I ended up using, and just being very careful with permissions. I found I was also having to symlink too much system stuff into the chroot to get it working. I would also accept the comment Koala Yeung left above if I could, as they helped me actually get the setup I thought I wanted.